# RabbitMQ java client load balancing in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-elb

We are using Amazon ELB for HA with RabbitMQ (3.2.4) and client (java spring rabbitmq).
If we've connected the java client to rabbit nodes it's ok.
If we've used the ELB as endpoint then there was a new connection every ~10-60 seconds.

PS:

We are using default ELB idle connection timeout is 60 seconds: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-idle-timeout.html

The error logs:

```
2016-04-19 09:14:11|Thread-13|[]|ERROR|com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor:Connection failed
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to connection error; cause: java.io.EOFException
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.processShutdownSignal(AMQChannel.java:283) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.startProcessShutdownSignal(ChannelN.java:267) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:573) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:509) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:503) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.close(AutorecoveringChannel.java:62) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor.internalReceiveCycle(EventProcessor.java:89) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor.processMessages(EventProcessor.java:50) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.EventListenerServer.lambda$startProcessing$0(EventListenerServer.java:74) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_72-internal]
2016-04-19 09:14:11|Thread-10|[]|ERROR|com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor:Connection failed
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to connection error; cause: java.io.EOFException
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.processShutdownSignal(AMQChannel.java:283) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.startProcessShutdownSignal(ChannelN.java:267) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:573) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:509) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:503) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.close(AutorecoveringChannel.java:62) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor.internalReceiveCycle(EventProcessor.java:89) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor.processMessages(EventProcessor.java:50) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.EventListenerServer.lambda$startProcessing$0(EventListenerServer.java:74) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_72-internal]
2016-04-19 09:14:11|Thread-20|[]|ERROR|com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor:Connection failed
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to connection error; cause: java.io.EOFException
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.processShutdownSignal(AMQChannel.java:283) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.startProcessShutdownSignal(ChannelN.java:267) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:573) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:509) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:503) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.close(AutorecoveringChannel.java:62) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor.internalReceiveCycle(EventProcessor.java:89) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor.processMessages(EventProcessor.java:50) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.EventListenerServer.lambda$startProcessing$0(EventListenerServer.java:74) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_72-internal]
2016-04-19 09:14:11|Thread-17|[]|ERROR|com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor:Connection failed
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to connection error; cause: java.io.EOFException
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.processShutdownSignal(AMQChannel.java:283) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.startProcessShutdownSignal(ChannelN.java:267) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:573) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:509) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:503) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.close(AutorecoveringChannel.java:62) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor.internalReceiveCycle(EventProcessor.java:89) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.consumer.EventProcessor.processMessages(EventProcessor.java:50) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.reporter.message.broker.rabbit.EventListenerServer.lambda$startProcessing$0(EventListenerServer.java:74) ~[rabbit-1.1.0-CP-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_72-internal]
```

Comment: Do you have a heartbeat < 60 seconds ?

Comment: Please suggest all what I need to change